# C# code-duplication : property List treatment

Tags: c#, code-duplication

I have a function which skim through a **list of object** (Genre, Nationality, etc). It has to return the **addition of a specific property** (Different for each object). I can't modify the code of these listed objects (in a DDL).

Here some examples of what I have to do for now :

```
    private String formatListString(List<Genre> list)
    {
        for (...)
        {
            str += list[i].Value;
            ...
        }
        return str;
    }

    private String formatListString(List<Nationality> list)
    {
        for (...)
        {
            str += list[i].Code;
            ...
        }
        return str;
    }
```

How can I make it in one single function ?
Maybe add a parameter in the function to specify the property to use ?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could pass in a selector delegate. Or pass in an already filtered list. Depending on what your `...`s leave out, there might be standard functions like `string.Concat` or `string.Join`.

Comment: `String.Concat` might be a worthwhile investigation. But it depends on what further logic your loop contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a lambda to select the property you need:

```
private String formatListString<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, string> selector)
    {
        for (...)
        {
            str += selector(list[i]);
            ...
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Call as follows:

```
var genres = formatListString(genreList, x => x.Value);
var nationalities = formatListString(nationalityList, x => x.Code);
```

The generic type parameter can be automatically inferred from the call, so you don't have to specify it explicitly (i.e. write `formatListString<Genre>(genreList, x => x.Value);`)

Answer (score 3):

```
return String.Join("...", list.Select(o => o.Code));
```

If that won't work for you, you could use generics and a lambda:

```
private string FormatList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, String> prop)
```

Comment: Just to note `String.Join` didn't get an overload that takes `IEnumerable<T>` until .NET 4 - if you're using an earlier version of the framework, you can call `.ToArray()` to make it work.

Comment: String.Join() is not sufficient for what I have to do. 
But your 2nd solution works great with the implementation of knittl. Thanks